# push three instance of an array to another single array - javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am working on JavaScript function and I am struggling big time.

I have 2 arrays.

Array 1 hold single record and array 2 hold say example 3 records. I want to push three records of array 2 in array 1 at same index of array1 record...

### this is what I want to achieve so that later on I can convert into JSON

```
       QualificationElemenetsAndComponents[0] = {

         Element [
                 ElementIndex : "",
                 ElementMarkingSchemeTitle : "",
                 ElementAvailableMark: "",
                 ElementPassMark: "",
                 ElementDistinctionMark: "",
                 Component[0]= [ 
                               componentIndex="", 
                               componentMark =""
                               ], 
                 Component[1]= [ 
                               componentIndex="", 
                               componentMark =""
                               ], 
                 Component[2]= [ 
                               componentIndex="", 
                               componentMark =""
                               ], 
                    }
```

### Example Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var selectedComponentList = [];

var selectElementList = [];

var QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList = [];


selectElementList = { 
                 ElementIndex: 1,
                 ElementMarkingSchemeTitle: “markingScheme1”,
                 ElementAvailableMark: 100,
                 ElementPassMark: 50,
                 ElementMeritMark: 60,
                 ElementDistinctionMark: 70
 };

 selectedComponentList = {
                componentIndex: 1,
                componentMark: 80
 };

 selectedComponentList = {
               componentIndex: 23,
               componentMark: 50
 };

 selectedComponentList = {
               componentIndex: 3,
               componentMark: 10
 };


 $(document).ready(function () {


 }); //end JQuery

</script>
```

Comment: Your JSON example is wrong. 
Using `selectedComponentList = {}` you simply reassigning a variable. If you want to push something to array use `selectedComponentList.push({}, {}, {})`. If you want to push an entire array to another array use `selectedComponentList.push.apply(selectedComponentList, anotherArray);`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to use Array.prototype.splice method.

```
z = [1,2,3];
z.splice(1,0,6,7,8,9);
console.log(z); // [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
var QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList = [];

var selectElementList = {//this is a javascript object
    ElementIndex: 1,
    ElementMarkingSchemeTitle: "markingScheme1",
    ElementAvailableMark: 100,
    ElementPassMark: 50,
    ElementMeritMark: 60,
    ElementDistinctionMark: 70
};
selectedComponentList = [];

selectedComponentList[selectedComponentList.length] = {
    componentIndex: 1,
    componentMark: 80
};

selectedComponentList[selectedComponentList.length] = {
    componentIndex: 23,
    componentMark: 50
};

selectedComponentList[selectedComponentList.length] = {
    componentIndex: 3,
    componentMark: 10
};

selectElementList.Component = selectedComponentList; //Here's how you assign the array to the object property

QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList[QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList.length] = selectElementList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work out please advice me if it is correct...

### build selectElementList

```
  selectElementList.push({ ElementIndex: E_RecordId, ElementMarkingSchemeTitle: E_MarkingSchemeTitle, ElementAvailableMark: E_AvailableMark, ElementPassMark: E_PassMark, ElementMeritMark: E_MeritMark, ElementDistinctionMark: E_DistinctionMark });
```

### build selectedComponentList

```
   selectedComponentList.push({ componentIndex: recordId, componentMark: ComponentSchemeMark });
```

### bind components (Array 2) to element (array1)

```
selectElementList.push({ Components: selectedComponentList });
```

### push array1 element with holding components to final array

```
QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList.push({ Element: selectElementList });
```

### Empty array1 and array2

```
selectElementList = [];
selectedComponentList = [];
```

and follow to repeat cycle for each element

following code produce the JSON output

```
 var myElementList = "";

 myElementList = JSON.stringify({ QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList: QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList });

 document.write("JSPN >>>>   " + myElementList);
```

### JSON output

```
JSPN >>>> {"QualificationElemenetsAndComponentsList":[{"Element":[{"ElementIndex":1,"ElementMarkingSchemeTitle":"m1","ElementAvailableMark":"10","ElementPassMark":"55","ElementMeritMark":"44","ElementDistinctionMark":"4"},{"Components":[{"componentIndex":1,"componentMark":"2"},{"componentIndex":2,"componentMark":"23"},{"componentIndex":3,"componentMark":"55"}]}]},{"Element":[{"ElementIndex":3,"ElementMarkingSchemeTitle":"m2","ElementAvailableMark":"45","ElementPassMark":"545","ElementMeritMark":"444","ElementDistinctionMark":"4"},{"Components":[{"componentIndex":2,"componentMark":"45"},{"componentIndex":4,"componentMark":"52"}]}]},{"Element":[{"ElementIndex":8,"ElementMarkingSchemeTitle":"m3","ElementAvailableMark":"100","ElementPassMark":"224","ElementMeritMark":"455","ElementDistinctionMark":"54"},{"Components":[{"componentIndex":2,"componentMark":"4"},{"componentIndex":1,"componentMark":"69"}]}]}]}
```